# How to Prevent java script file load multiple times when loading view through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a view which is loaded by `load()` method of AJAX and that view contains the following JS script to check that the `PurchaseRFQ` is loaded, and if so once then avoid second it loading next time.

But still `PurchaseRFQ` is loading multiple times. Please suggest me how to solve this.

```
try {
  if (jQueryUI) {
    jQueryUI();

    if (PurchaseRFQ) {
      PurchaseRFQ(); // this object contains my js script
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception) {
  $.getScript("../Scripts/jQueryUi.js");
  $.getScript("../Scripts/PurchaseOrderScript/RFQ.js", function() {
  PurchaseRFQ();
})
}
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code properly. This had a *lot* of needless whitespace which made it much harder to read than necessary

Comment: Probably I misunderstood the situation, so I deleted my answer. IMHO it's not a good way to ajax call a view that has a script like that loaded everytime. It's a good way instead to have scripts outside those type of files and setup some events to call after ajax call is successful.